# Web design issue with images in template and page editors

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am new to the whole of web designing, and I have a great deal of difficulty pinpointing the source of problem. I can't google the solution because I don't know what the problem was. Basically, I am trying to set up the single image that changes when you click on button. The strange part is that my code (all the functions that control images through buttons) actually does work when I wrote it inside the template editor of web builder. But then, I finally made my own template which consists of pure coding for lay outs only, not all the images and buttons.

I put that images and buttons code in another place where you edit individual page. Suddenly, I can't seem to activate the functions (buttons that change images) anymore, even though the picture is visible. It just won't change the picture. I am not sure if it is because of web builder itself or that there is something wrong with my coding (provided below).

One possible clue is that the editor automatically put ![CDATA[ or something when I wrote this code in page editor. That ![CDATA thing doesn't show up when I put code in template editor.

```
    <script language="JavaScript">// <![CDATA[
    var a1 = new Image();
    a1.src = "a111.jpg"; 

    var imgs = ['a111.jpg', 'a11.jpg', 'a33.jpg','a44.jpg'];

    function changeImageR() {

    if (roomID == 0) {
    var img = document["buttonOne"];
    if (!img._index) img._index = 0;
    img.src = imgs[img._index++];
    if (img._index >= imgs.length) img._index = 0;}  

    }

    // ]]></script>

    <br /><br /><form style="font-size: 100%;"> 
    <table border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="a111.jpg" border="0" alt="click me" width="620" height="270" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><br /> <input onclick="changeImageR('textarea1')" name="buttonOne"     type="button" value="Turn Right" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="font-size: xx-small; text-align: center;"><br /><textarea   id="textarea1" cols="53" rows="5"> </textarea></div>
     </form>
```

Comment: Use the web console or error console to see javascript errors in Firefox, in other decent browsers there are similar tools/windows. It's next to impossible to troubleshoot javascript without one :-)

In this case it might simply be that roomID is not defined?

Then you set img to document['buttonOne'] but that's the button, not an image, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.. change the button to an image?

Comment: I am trying to change the image to a different image when I click on a button. But thanks, your comment is still an advice.

Answer (score 0):

The spacing in your code is wonky so its hard to tell, but the CDATA tag won't be a problem if it is commented out, which it appears to be. One problem I noticed, in the onchange event when you call changeImageR you are passing a parameter. However your changeImageR function does not accept a parameter.